# How to set upload path after renaming uploads folder in Multisite?

Tags: multisite, uploads

I encountered a specific issue. Tried to google the answer out but no results or maybe I'm choosing wrong search queries. I on multisite install and recently tried to change the name of `uploads` folder and moving it out of `wp-content` folder. I put simple line of code into the wp-config file:

```
define( 'UPLOADS', 'media' );
```

I moved all the uploads content to the new folder. Everything works fine but only for the main site. The other sub-site which is supposed to be the shop doesn't have anything which depends on uploads folder loaded, neither images nor css styles generated by the theme and being located in newly created `media` folder. I tried to change two settings in super-admin panel: the `Upload Path` to `/home/servername/public_html/media/` and `Upload Url Path` to `https://example.com/media/` but it doesn't work. What exactly should I write into Upload Path and Upload URL Path boxes to make it work?

All help would be much appreciated, best regards, Dan.

PS: WordPress is installed in public_html folder directly.

**SOME MORE INFO**

the sub-site's address is `https://example.com/shop/`, all the images on the sub-site point to `https://example.com/shop/media/` instead of `https://example.com/media/`.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one could help me with this issue I tried a bit of trial and error hoping nothing will be broken on the site. Apparently removing `define( 'UPLOADS', 'media' );` bit from wp-config.php did the job. The Upload Url Path and Upload Path from the question above remained unchanged. Everything is being loaded properly now.

Best regards, Dan.